# Network doesn't work on boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, networking

I've setup my `/etc/network/interfaces`. But **I have to always restart my network**, not just start. `/etc/init.d/networking restart` on the system boot. Where is the problem? I want my network to **start automatically** on system boot up. Could you please help me?

My /etc/network/interfaces config

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Maybe rc.local could help me, but I don't think, it's the right way to do it. Or isn't it?

Comment: Is the behavior the same if you comment out the hotplug line?

Comment: @chili555 still the same

Comment: Are you certain the interface is eth0? `ifconfig` Are there any clues in the message log? `dmesg | grep eth` Is it possible that 192.168.1.21 is in the DHCP pool used by the router? Is there any improvement if you specify 192.168.1.150?